# every .htaccess results in a 401

Tags: mysql, apache, .htaccess

recently I have been encountering a problem. Every .htaccess, no matter if I set it in the apache config or in a separate .htaccess file, results in error 401 after login. Ownership of the password file is correct. Here is the Directory statement.

```
 <Directory /var/www/test/>
            AllowOverride none
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName Documents
            AuthBasicProvider file
            AuthUserFile /var/htp/.htpasswd
            Require user xxx
 </Directory>
```

The server was a clean Ubuntu install and I installed iRedMail as the first services -- worked like a charm but a recent apt-get upgrade must have broken something. The only line I get in the error.log is:

[Tue Jan 27 17:32:29.129776 2015] [:error] [pid 16979] No requires line available

So now I know this has something to do with the mysql auth of apache but I am just trying to use straight basic auth here. I can disable mysql auth as it is required by other services but as it stands any folder which is protected by a .htaccess is not accessible.

Any hints? I have been banging my head against the wall for two days now. nginx is not an option due to iRedMail.

Best
Patrick

Comment: You have a directory statement in your htaccess file?

Comment: No, this is from the apache config. I just tried various ways.